# jquery offset top wrong value, but gets right on page resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, offset, sticky, window-resize

I want to achieve a sticky menu like the left navigation on this page: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html.

My menu is a `nav` element with `position:relative` (I tried `static` as well) that goes `fixed` when it reaches the top of the viewport.

here's my function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function stickyNav() {
        var elementPosition = $('nav').offset();
        console.log(elementPosition);

        $(window).scroll(function(){
            if($(window).scrollTop() > elementPosition.top){
                $('nav').addClass("sticky");
            } else {
                $('nav').removeClass("sticky");
            }
        });
    }
    stickyNav();
}); //document ready
```

the `console.log(elementPosition);` returns an offset top of around 1200px on page load, which is wrong. But if i resize the page, the value changes to around 650px which is the correct offset top and the function does what it is supposed to be doing.

I've looked around and found out that offsetp top maybe wrong when it's on hidden elements, or it has issues with margins but I actually don't have any complex structure here, just a single visible `nav` element .

any help on figuring this out would be much appreciated! thanks!!

Comment: Where is stickyNav() called in your code as I don't see an invocation of it? Can you share the html for the nav tag that produces this issue?

Comment: @DennisShtatnov updated, thanks

Comment: Here is a minimally functioning example of your code working: https://jsfiddle.net/b4m3swhp/1/. I'd suspect it is something to do with the structure of where <nav> is being placed or when it was inserted. If a resize is fixing it then it may be possible that some of your css is responsive and effecting the <nav> tag when the screen is a particular width.

Answer (score 3):

`jQuery(document).ready` handler occurs when the DOM is ready. Not when the page is fully rendered.

https://api.jquery.com/ready/

> When using scripts that rely on the value of CSS style properties,
>   it's important to reference external stylesheets or embed style
>   elements before referencing the scripts.
>
> In cases where code relies on loaded assets (for example, if the
>   dimensions of an image are required), the code should be placed in a
>   handler for the load event instead.

So if you're using stylesheets that are loaded AFTER the script in question, or the layout of the page depends on image sizes, or other content, the `ready` event will be hit when the page is not in its final rendering state.

You can fix that by:

1. Making sure you include all stylesheets before the script
2. Making sure the CSS is more robust, and doesn't depend that much on content size (such as images)
3. Or, you can do this on window `load` event.

## Edit:

If you want to make your script dependent on more than one async event (like the [loadCSS](https://github.com/filamentgroup/loadCSS) library), use this:

```
var docReady = jQuery.Deferred();
var stylesheet = loadCSS( "path/to/mystylesheet.css" );
var cssReady = jQuery.Deferred();
onloadCSS( stylesheet, function() {
    cssReady.resolve();
});
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    docReady.resolve($);
});
jQuery.when(docReady, cssReady).then(function($) {
    //define stickyNav

    stickyNav();
});
```

Comment: that's a good answer! In fact my css is loaded asynchronously (https://github.com/filamentgroup/loadCSS) could that be why this is happening? is there a way to have the function kick in after the css is appended? thanks

Comment: You could create a `Deferred` jQuery object for every async loading that you have: document ready, css load, etc. After every load, simply resolve the promise.
So put your code instead inside a `jQuery.when(promises).then(functionWhenAllIsOk, functionWhenNotAllOk)`

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/

You can use that with your `loadCSS` using this:
`var stylesheet = loadCSS( "path/to/mystylesheet.css" );
onloadCSS( stylesheet, function() {
    console.log( "Stylesheet has loaded." );
});`

Answer (score -1):

You can add a check to see if your CSS has loaded by setting a style tag in your document which shows a test element, and then overwrite this in your CSS file to hide it. Then you can check the status of your page by checking this element. For example...

In your HTML:

```
<div id="loaded-check" style="display:block; height:10px; width:10px; position:fixed;"></div>
```

In your CSS:

```
#loaded-check { display:none; }
```

In your jQuery script:

```
var startUp = function() {
    var cssLoaded = $('#loaded-check').is(':visible');
    if (cssLoaded) {
        $('#loaded-check').remove();
        doOtherStuff()
    }
    else {
        setTimeout(function() {
            startUp();
        }, 10);
    }
}

var doOtherStuff = function () {
    //bind your sticky menu and any other functions reliant on DOM load here
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what the on load event is for.

Comment: Actually the onload event is for when the DOM had loaded and is nothing to do with the browser applying css styles. There is often a lag between these 2 events. Often I see people using a timeout to try and avoid getting element heights or offsets too early in the page load. My solution was just aiming to be a slightly more controlled approach than that.